# How to extract list of docker images inside GCP artifact registry

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform

I want to list all the repositories inside GCP artifact registry in golang.

Current code : (https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/apiv1beta2)

```
    c, err := artifactregistry.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("<service account json>"))
    if err != nil {
        // no error here
    }
    defer c.Close()

    req := &artifactregistrypb.ListRepositoriesRequest{
        Parent: "<project-id>",
    }
    it := c.ListRepositories(ctx, req)
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println("resp", resp)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("err ==>", err)
        }
    }
```

The error prints: `Invalid field value in the request.` OR sometimes I get `Request contains an invalid argument`

What am I doing wrong here ? and What does the "Parent" mean ? (in ListRepositoriesRequest)

On further digging, I found that the value passed in the Parent goes to : "x-goog-request-params", what should be the correct format for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime the libraries/api are well documented, sometime not...

[Here the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.repositories/list) that you can test in the API explorer (right hand side bar). After some tests, the parent must have that format

```
projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>
```

Try with that to solve your issue